# Boolean subtraction

Tags: boolean, bit, boolean-logic, subtraction, plc

I have got a PLC program.
In the program i got an error handler function, it has 1 bit output.
If there is any problem (with the machine) the output is **TRUE**.

My problem is, there are some machine fault, what i don't want to report to the central system monitoring PLC, but I would displayed on the OP.

so...  with other words ...

`A + B + C + ... + T + U + V + a + b + c + d = X`

Where:
    - all uppercase letters are the unknown sourced machine faults (more than 200 fault bit)
    - all lowercase letters are those faults what I don't want to report (4-5 fault bit)
    - X is the function output (1 bit)

What I know:
 - the function output (X)
 - faults what I don't want to report (a, b, c, d)

What I need:
    - the unknown sourced machine faults (A + B + C + ... + T + U + V)
    `X - (a + b + c + d) = A + B + C + ... + T + U + V`

*How can I substract these variable from the result?*

In the boolean algebra 
OR logic acts as an addition + 
AND logic acts as a multiplication * 
***Which** logic acts as a subtraction? or **How** do I get  A + B + C + ... + T + U + V?*

Comment: I have the impression that you are making your error handler way too complicated...you should strieve for clarity not obfuscation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then what you want is not generally possible.

A logical OR throws away source information. Only if it returns **0** then you have full information about all its inputs: they must all be **0**. As soon as it returns **1**, then there is no way to reconstruct the individual inputs, except for the fact that they are not all **0**.

I'll show what is possible, using several situations + what you can conclude from it:

- X == 0 **-->** all of (**A..V**) and (**a..d**) are **0**.
- X == 1 and all of (**a..d**) are 0 **-->** at least 1 of (**A..V**) is **1**.
- X == 1 and at least 1 of (**a..d**) is 1 **-->** nothing can be said about the values of (**A..V**). They could all be **0**, or all **1**, or any combination in between.